# WSL-2: Which ports are automatically forwarded?

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, portforwarding, wsl-2

I've been tinkering around with WSL-2 for a while now and don't exactly understand how traffic is routed between the host and WSL-2 dist.

In some sources it seems like all ports used by WSL-2 automatically become available to the host machine. Such as in [this tutorial by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/python/web-frameworks#hello-world-tutorial-for-flask).
Similarly I managed to host a Jupyter instance which is available directly on my host machine through `localhost:8888`.

However, when trying other services, such as ssh (also tried on a non-standard port) the port does not automatically become available through localhost and I have to use the IP address assigned to my WSL distro (the one from `wsl hostname -I`)

To make the services available through localhost I found [this portforwarding script](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150#issuecomment-504209723), which worked. But I would like to understand why it was needed.

Why is port forwarding needed for some services, but not all?

Answer (score 39):

When you run WSL-2, a machine like a vitural machin run on your window device. Windows will create a local network, same your LAN, and connect WLS-2 to this network.

- On your WSL2, you can run *ip a | grep eth0*, result look like:

> 5: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
> inet 172.27.5.124/20 brd 172.27.15.255 scope global eth0

- And on terminal (or PowerShell) on your windows, run *ipconfig*, find in the result, look like:

```
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1532:a8ea:6b34:8df2%73
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.27.0.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

WSL-2 and Windows device on a same network, and WSL-2 not connect to your LAN.

My solution (use port forwarding on Windows)

Open terminal with Admin on Windows, and run script:

```
netsh interface portproxy set v4tov4 listenport=8888 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=8888 connectaddress=$(wsl hostname -I)
```

Answer (score 28):

My confusion came from firewall issues with WSL-2.

What I have found is:

- Services listening on ports in WSL-2 are accesible from the host machine as `localhost:<port>`
- WSL-2 ports are not accessible from outside of the host machine
- WSL-2 ports can be made available through `netstat interface portproxy` or other portforward tools using the ip address of the WSL instance.

The firewall did not allow acces to the WSL ports by just listing the ports. I had to specifcally select the `iphlpsv` service (IP Helper service) in my firewall rules to allow traffic through to the WSL instance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you managed to host a Jupyter instance? I'm trying to ssh through wsl.exe to an EC2 instance and I think this elaboration will help.

Answer (score 6):

Following these steps helped me connect to my ports locally on Windows:

1. use the script in [here](https://dev.to/vishnumohanrk/wsl-port-forwarding-2e22) and change the ports to the ones that you need to forward. Save this file to a path.
2. In wsl, `sudo apt install net-tools`
3. In powershell (administrator mode), `type ".\script.ps1" | powershell.exe -c -`. This is to run the file. Right-clicking the file to "Run with powershell" won't work.
4. To test that it works, in powershell, type `netsh interface portproxy show v4tov4`

Answer (score 1):

There may be conflicts between `netsh interface portproxy` and the WSL "magic" port forwarders attempting to start listening on the same (TCP) port, according to output of `netstat -an | findstr ":PORT_NUMBER"`.

Let's say a Linux service is started.  It listens to a TCP port 443. WSL wires the Windows's `localhost:443` to the Linux service's port 443.  This is visible to `netstat` showing a listener on `localhost:443` that is not wired as a connection.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> netstat -an | findstr ":443"
[...]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:443          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

Attempting to forward from any other network interface's port 443 to `localhost:443` with `netsh` does not show an error but is seen in `netstat` as an unexpected listener on a different TCP port.  I consider this a bug of `netsh interface portproxy`.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> netsh interface portproxy set v4tov4 listenport=443 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=443 connectaddress=127.0.0.1

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> curl.exe -iskS https://10.X.Y.Z/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.X.Y.Z port 443 after 2022 ms: Connection refused


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> netsh interface portproxy show v4tov4

Listen on ipv4:             Connect to ipv4:

Address         Port        Address         Port
--------------- ----------  --------------- ----------
[...]
0.0.0.0         443         127.0.0.1       443
```

I believe I caught `netsh interface portproxy` red-handed after seeing a TCP connection from an unexpectedly random TCP port on the unexpected interface `127.0.0.1` to `127.0.0.1:443`,

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> netstat -an | findstr ":443"
[...]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:443          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63916        127.0.0.1:443          TIME_WAIT
```

If the above theory of a bug in `netsh` is correct, I can understand why my earlier intuitive separation of port numbers worked.  That is, the Linux service can be configured to listen to a different port number such as 10443, and then the Windows side can be set up to forward from port 443 to `localhost:10443`.

I guess the same conflict might have caused the original post's situation if a `netsh interface portproxy` forwarding is set up before starting the Linux service.

*Update.*  It seems my current woes are due to a corprorate-enforced firewall manager on my laptop.  My answer above is not credible.

Answer (score 1):

Why is the port forwarding needed for wsl2? After I watched this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCK3easuYm4), and read through [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150), I learned that wsl1 used to just work, and port forwarding was not necessary; but beyond that I haven't gone too in far depth (something to do with wsl2 being hyper-v now).

In any case, I created this powershell script, below, inspired by this famous [script](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150#issuecomment-504209723).

I was trying to port forward the Expo port, to be able to run my react native app on my physical android device by connecting to my windows pc's wifi network address. The port exposed by `expo start --dev-client` is `8081` so that is what is in the script below (but any port could be used).

```
echo "Running WSL Port Forward Script...";

$wslAddrTxt = bash.exe -c "ip addr | grep -Ee 'inet.*eth0'"
$found = $wslAddrTxt -match '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}';

if( !$found ){
  echo "The Script Exited, the ip address of WSL 2 cannot be found";
  exit;
}

$wslAddr = $matches[0];
$PCWifiNetworkAddr = (Test-Connection -ComputerName (hostname) -Count 1 | Select -ExpandProperty IPv4Address).IPAddressToString;

#[Ports]
#All the ports you want to forward separated by coma
$ports=@(8081);
$ports_a = $ports -join ",";

for( $i = 0; $i -lt $ports.length; $i++ ){
  $port = $ports[$i];
  # This deletion and re-adding below is required, even if they were the same as before.
  #   This is because the rules applied by the netsh command don't seem to apply after the PC is rebooted.
  #   Even if you run `netsh interface portproxy show all` and it shows the correct rules, it doesn't seem to work after the PC is rebooted, unless you delete and re-add the rule.
  # NOTE: The above comment doesn't seem to be a problem if the listenaddress omitted entirely, or is set to a static value of "0.0.0.0" (which means all IPv4 address for the PC)
  #   Omitting the listenaddress entirely sets its value to "*", or, according the documentation, "the local computer" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-interface-portproxy#add-v4tov4.
  netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=$port listenaddress=$PCWifiNetworkAddr;
  netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=$port listenaddress=$PCWifiNetworkAddr connectport=$port connectaddress=$wslAddr;

  Write-Output ("Successfully forwarded WSL Port " + $wslAddr + ":" + $port + " to PC Host Port " + $PCWifiNetworkAddr + ":" + $port);
}
```

The above code:

- Automatically gets the pc's wifi ip address, and the wsl2 ip address
- Creates the port forwarding rule

An odd thing about the listenaddress:

If `listenaddress` is set to a specific ip address, then the port forward rule will stop working after reboot, even though running `netsh interface portproxy show all` command shows that the rule still exists. If the rule is deleted and re-added again though, then it starts working again.
If the `listenaddress` is, instead, set to `0,0.0.0` (or if `listenaddress` is omitted entirely) then rebooting is no longer an issue that causes the rule to stop applying. From a quick online search, it seems the reason is more or less that the `netsh interface portproxy` command [has a few quirks](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/zj1cr4/windows_netsh_interface_portproxy_resets_after/), in some scenarios; but I'm still not sure of the cause, exactly.

I'm also not sure if setting `listenaddress` to `0.0.0.0` (which means all addresses), or omitting `listenaddress` entirely, is "bad". Most of the tutorials I've seen set the `listenaddress` to `0.0.0.0` ([microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-interface-portproxy#add-v4tov4) calls it setting it to "the local computer").

Alas, I felt there were several reasons it would be nice to run this script, automatically, on Startup:

1. If ip addresses change, I don't have to really think about it. At worst I reboot my pc, and it just works.
2. The strange issue with `netsh` not persisting rules with specific `listenaddress` defined was annoying to deal with.

I put the above script in a powershell file, then created a windows Task Scheduler task to run it on startup (or user logon, rather, as it was easier). Here's how I configured the Task:

##### Making the Port Forward Script Run On PC Reboot, Using Windows Task Scheduler

- First, put the powershell script, from the previous step above, into a powershell file (I put mine in `C:\projects\wslPortForwardStartup.ps1`)
- In Windows Search, Type `Task Scheduler` , and select it
- On the right hand side of the Task Scheduler window (under “Actions”), click “Create Task”
- Under “General” tab:

  - Name the Task `WSL Port Forwarding Startup Task`
  - Change “Configure for:” to Windows 10 (or whatever windows version you’re on)
  - Check on “Run with highest privileges” checkbox
- Under “Triggers”

  - Click “New”
  - Change “Begin the task:” to “At logon”
  - (Optionally) Change from “Any user” to “Specific User” (should be auto set to your logged in user, not necessary to change)
- Under “Actions”

  - Click New
  - Under “Program/script:” put `powershell` (note: do not put the path to your powershell script here)
  - Under “Add arguments”, this is not optional, this is where your script path goes. Eg
    `-command C:\projects\wslPortForwardStartup.ps1`
- Under “Conditions”

  - Uncheck “Tart the task only if the computer is on AC power”
  - Uncheck “Start only if the following network connection is available”
- Click OK as many times as you need to
- Open powershell and run `netsh interface portproxy show all` to check that the port forwarding rule hasn’t already been applied.
- Reboot your PC

  - After logging in you should see a terminal window popup with a message `Running WSL Port Forward Script...`
  - Once the script is done, open powershell and check that the port forwarding rule has been applied, using the `netsh interface portproxy show all` command.
  - If you don’t see it, open the Task Scheduler to troubleshoot

    - Under “Active Tasks” scroll until you see  `WSL Port Forwarding Startup Task` (or whatever you named it) and double click on it
    - Choose “Properties” on the right hand side (Note: you can also change your task’s configuration here)
    - Choose “History”, and double click on any “Error” or “Warning”

Of course, I also had to open port 8081 on windows firewall, to allow inbound connections, if I wanted to connect to my PC's port 8081 over my home wifi network. Here's a quick powershell script I made to do that (though opening the windows firewall settings is almost just as easy).

Note, this firewall script below only needs to be run/applied once:

```
New-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName 'WSL 2 Firewall Unlock' -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 8081 -Profile Private -Action Allow -Protocol TCP
```