# Cannot reach docker container through WSL2

Tags: docker

I run into an issue with a docker and WSL2 configuration that was running ok for weeks...

I'm running a docker Apache2 web server on Ubuntu WSL2 with port forwarding.
I can see using nmap the 8080 Ubuntu port is open when docker image is running.

I can curl the web server from within the Ubuntu WSL2 using both 127.0.0.1:8080 and eth0 inet address (172.17.118.136:8080) and get the apache default page.
I have an issue when trying to access the web server from my Windows host with the Ubuntu eth0 inet address : connection timed out.

From my Windows host the ping of Ubuntu eth0 is ok, and when I run an Apache2 web server directly from Ubuntu WSL2 (no docker), my Windows host is able to connect to it using eth0 inet address.

Comment: Can you try using `netsh interface portproxy` to forward traffic from the windows host to the WSL2 guest? See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/68872599/530160

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue thanks to jishi comment on
this thread : https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4983#issuecomment-602487077

Using the ipv6 localhost url [::1] worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following lsof command in WSL2 to find out on which port the docker is running and then use that port to connect:

```
sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN
```

You will get a result like this:
[image]

The port for me is 49157:
so, I can access the *Docker container which is inside WSL* through Windows by `http://localhost:49157` or by wsl inet ip -> `http://172.31.255.167:49157`

---

Note: if lsof is not installed then use the following command to install it:

```
sudo apt install lsof
```

Comment: I already knew the docker ports therefore it didn't solve the issue in my case